# Dom pdf is return a weird string of code instead of a pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-dompdf

I have set up Dom pdf in my Laravel project, but when I generate the pdf, the controller only return a 'weird string of code' instead of the pdf.

My code in te controller:

```
public function pdfConditions(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'html' => 'required'
        ]);

        $html = $request->html;

        $data = compact('html');

        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.conditions', $data);
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $pdf->setWarnings(false);

        return $pdf->download();
    }
```

My code in my views blade file:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
    {{ $html }}
</body>
```

The response I receive:

[image]

So what can be the reason the pdf is not generated properly?

Comment: That's **normal**, Because it will pass in your *blade* file.